# R preserve symbol names across indirection

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a plot like so...

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = ttd, y = aval)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.25)
```

That gave me a nice plot with `ttd` and `aval` as my axes labels. I like how it used the names of the arguments as the default labels.

However, I have a bunch of plots like this, and I wanted to abstract it into my own *function*. But I can't seem to make the plot from inside the function. Here's what I tried:

```
bw_plot <- function(data, x_, y_) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x = substitute(x_), y = substitute(y_))) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.25)
}

bw_plot(my_data, ttd, aval)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : object 'x_' not found
```

I simply want to pass the symbols down from my `bw_plot` function into `ggplot`. **How can I get it to see my actual column names?**

(I also tried passing the column names in as strings and calling `as.name` on them, but i get the same result.

Comment: If you pass column names as symbols, you should use `aes_q()` rather than `aes()`; for strings, `aes_string()` works. But as @ArtemSokolov's answer details, recent versions of ggplot also support unquoting with `!!` in `aes()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substitute` will correctly "quote" your arguments `x_` and `y_`. However, `aes` will apply a second round of "quoting" internally, which is what gives you the error. You need to unquote the result of your `substitute` calls, as you're passing them to `aes`. This can be done using `!!` operator from `rlang`.

```
library( ggplot2 )
library( rlang )
bw_plot <- function( .data, x_, y_ )
{
  xsym <- ensym(x_)
  ysym <- ensym(y_)
  ggplot( .data, aes(x = !!xsym, y = !!ysym) ) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point(alpha=0.25)
}
```

Note that the correct function to use is `rlang::ensym`, rather than `substitute`, because you are aiming to capture individual symbols (column names). Also, I suggest not naming your argument `data` to avoid name collisions with a built-in function.

Here's example usage: `bw_plot( mtcars, mpg, wt )`
[image]

Comment: Tried this code. Getting this error: `Error in !ensym(x_) : invalid argument type`

Comment: Hmm... is it a version issue? Doing `bw_plot( mtcars, mpg, wt )` works for me on R 3.4.4, rlang 0.2.1, and ggplot2 2.2.1.9000.

Comment: According to `sessionInfo()` I have the all the same versions. When I type ``?`!!` ``, I get the right help page. I'm working from RStudio server if that makes a difference.

Comment: I don't think RStudio server would make a difference. Maybe try creating an empty file, pasting only the example along with the necessary libraries, then run it in a fresh R session? It's possible there are some lingering naming conflicts (e.g., from when you were using `data` as a variable name).

Comment: I guess it might be good to rule-out a potential RStudio server issue by running the example in a stand-alone R session.

Comment: Same result in a fresh session as well as in the command line (without RStudio) :/

Comment: @AndyCarlson 2.2.1.9000 was the dev version for ggplot2 for about 1.5 years with plenty of changes, so that version number doesn't tell much. Maybe try with the latest, 3.0.0?

Comment: @AndyCarlson: Can you please try separating `ensym` from `!!` to see which one gives you trouble? I just modified the example to demonstrate one way to do this.

Comment: It works using the new `ggplot2_3.0.0` version! I re-ran the example on `ggplot2_2.2.1` and got this: `Error in !xsym : invalid argument type`.

Comment: @AndyCarlson Aha, so the issue is in `!!`. If you look at the help page for this operator, there's an alternative formulation as a function. If you replace `!!xsym` with `UQ(xsym)`, it should work with the older packages. (However, I would caution against widespread usage of `UQ`, as [the function is on its way to being deprecated](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html).)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works for ggplot2 version `2.2.1.9000` and later. For versions `2.2.1` and prior, it looks like the non-standard evaluation used by `aes` makes this impossible. Instead, I have to use `aes_` which provides an "escape hatch" allowing me to provide the symbols to the function as expected. Here is the solution:

```
bw_plot <- function(data, x_, y_) {
  ggplot(data, aes_(x = substitute(x_), y = substitute(y_))) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.25)
}

bw_plot(my_data, ttd, aval)
```